# Does windows 7 have refresh option like in windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore, reset, refresh

I know there are backup and restore option in windows 7 but I don't see very useful "refresh" option like in Windows 8 or 10.

Is there one?

Comment: You mean like "Reset to factory settings" or something like that? I don't think there's an option, but you can always use the Windows installation media and enter system recovery mode...

Comment: No, there is not one in W7.